# About Wemos D1 WiFi

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide

I bought the Wemos D1 WiFi and I am wondering how to operate this. So, inside the Arduino IDE, I downloaded ESP8266 boards, I see WeMos D1 mini, WeMos D1 R1, and WeMos mini Pro/Lite.

Why in the world don't I see Wemos D1?

How can I operate this board without the D1 board to select in the Arduino IDE?

Is there a way to add, or anyways to operate it?

I don't mind using other software besides the Arduino IDE if it's the only way to work with D1.

Board:

[image: WeMos D1]

I get this Error when trying to upload D1 R1:

```
C:\...\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\tools\esptool\2.5.0-3-20ed2b9/esptool.exe -vv -cd nodemcu -cb 115200 -cp COM6 -ca 0x00000 -cf         
C:\...\Temp\arduino_build_179604/sketch_jan15a.ino.bin 
esptool v0.4.13-1-gf80ae31 - (c) 2014 Ch. Klippel <ck@atelier-klippel.de>
setting board to nodemcu
setting baudrate from 115200 to 115200
setting port from COM1 to COM6
setting address from 0x00000000 to 0x00000000
espcomm_upload_file
espcomm_upload_mem
setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
opening bootloader
resetting board
trying to connect
flush start
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
flush complete
espcomm_send_command: sending command header
espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
flush start
setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
flush complete
espcomm_send_command: sending command header
espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
espcomm_send_command: receiving 2 bytes of data
Uploading 287488 bytes from 
C:\...\arduino_build_179604/sketch_jan15a.ino.bin to flash at 0x00000000
erasing flash
size: 046300 address: 000000
first_sector_index: 0
total_sector_count: 71
head_sector_count: 16
adjusted_sector_count: 55
erase_size: 037000
espcomm_send_command: sending command header
espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
setting serial port timeouts to 15000 ms
read 0, requested 1
setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
warning: espcomm_send_command: didn't receive command response
warning: espcomm_send_command(FLASH_DOWNLOAD_BEGIN) failed
closing bootloader
flush start
setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
flush complete
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

Comment: this is D1 R1 .

Answer (score 2):

Your board is a WeMos D1 R1. You need to select **Tools > Board > WeMos D1 R1** in the Arduino IDE.

Here's a good comparison of the difference between the WeMos D1 R1 and the WeMos D1 R2:
https://github.com/arendst/Sonoff-Tasmota/wiki/Wemos-D1-R1-&-R2

Comment: I forgot to mention that I get an error when trying to upload WeMos D1 R1.